# How to remove ^c mark from own shell?

Tags: linux, terminal, signals, gnome-terminal

In normal terminal, If we run command like 'top' and when we pass interrupt signal through ctrl+c, command terminates But in my own shell it also terminate but also print ^c in the terminal. How can I prevent to print ^c. I need system call to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:
`stty -echoctl`

**Edit (after OP specified that a system call is needed):**  See [man tcsetattr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr) and the **non-POSIX** `ECHOCTL` terminal attribute.

Comment: sir, I need system call to do this.